# Float Value Not Working

Tags: objective-c, ios

Okay, I have been trying to get the float value to work. I have two fields name `RingNumber` and `NumberOfSides`

I am trying to add them together.

Here is my code. What could be going wrong here? According to the tutorial, this is all correct.

```
float x = ([RingNumber.text floatValue]);
float y = x+([NumberOfSides.text floatValue]);

Answer.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%2.f", y];
```

Comment: You have not told us what the problem is.

Comment: Shouldn't that format specifier be `%.2f`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
Answer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", y];
```